# How to read CSV after metadata?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file like this:

```
#Description
#Param1: value
#Param2: value
...
#ParamN: value

Time (s),Header1,Header2
243.41745,3,1
243.417455,3,5
243.41746,7,6
...
```

I need to read it with Python without using Pandas as requirement. How to read the CSV data itself ignoring the initial lines until the empty one? I am using the code below that successfully reads the metadata.

```py
def read(file_path: str):
    '''Read the data of the Digilent WaveForms Logic Analyzer Acquisition
    (moodel Discovery2).

    Parameter: File path.
    '''
    meta = {}
    RE_CONFIG = re.compile(r'^#(?P<name>[^:]+)(: *(?P<value>.+)\s*$)*')
    with open(file_path, 'r') as fh:
        # Read the metadata and description at the beginning of the file.
        for line in fh.readlines():
            line = line.strip()
            if not line:
                break
            config = RE_CONFIG.match(line)
            if config:
                if not config.group('value'):
                    meta.update({'Description': config.group('name')})
                else:
                    meta.update({config.group('name'): config.group('value')})
        # Read the data it self.
        data = csv.DictReader(fh, delimiter=',')
    return data, meta
```

Comment: And does this not work?

Comment: Not the `csv.DictReader(fh, delimiter=',')` part. I want the answer as `{'Time (s)': [], 'Header1': [], 'Header2': []}`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work. I had to change `for line in fh.readlines():` to `for line in fh:` the portion that reads the meta-data so line with data *wouldn't* be read, *then* create the `DictReader` and use it to get the `data`.

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint, pp
import re

def read(file_path: str):
    '''Read the data of the Digilent WaveForms Logic Analyzer Acquisition
    (moodel Discovery2).

    Parameter: File path.
    '''
    meta = {}
    RE_CONFIG = re.compile(r'^#(?P<name>[^:]+)(: *(?P<value>.+)\s*$)*')
    with open(file_path, 'r') as fh:
        # Read the metadata and description at the beginning of the file.
        for line in fh:  # CHANGED
            line = line.strip()
            if not line:
                break
            config = RE_CONFIG.match(line)
            if config:
                if not config.group('value'):
                    meta.update({'Description': config.group('name')})
                else:
                    meta.update({config.group('name'): config.group('value')})

        # Read the data itself.
        reader = csv.DictReader(fh, delimiter=',')
        data = list(reader)

    return data, meta

res = read('mixed.csv')
pprint(res)
```